I get an error Could not get unknown property 'user' for root project 'sudir-provider' when I add credentials for my custom maven repo
I get an error
Could not get unknown property 'user' for root project 'sudir-provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
when I add credentials for my custom maven repo.When using a regular Maven repository, without adding credentials, there is no such error. how do I fix this?
my build.gradle file
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'idea' }

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'password'
        }
        url 'https://my.custom.repo/'    
      } 
     }

group = 'axbit.sudir' 
version = '0.0.1' 
description = 'sudir-provider'

ext {
    keycloakVersion = "21.1.1" }


dependencies {
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-core:${keycloakVersion}"
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:${keycloakVersion}"
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private:${keycloakVersion}"
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-services:${keycloakVersion}"
    implementation 'javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0'

}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    } 
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' 
}

